# How can I add contextual information to a LoggerAdapter instance AFTER it has been instantiated?

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to inject contextual information into a LoggerAdapter instance (that already has a set of 'extra' parms) and have it persist throughout the lifetime of the object? I have a parameter I want to inject in a particular method, but I also need other methods that use the instance to have that injected parameter. I kinda tried to do logger.extra["foo"] = "FOO" but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import sys

def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    adapter = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra={'foo': 'bar'})
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s [%(foo)s]'))
    logger.addHandler(sh)
    adapter.warning('This is a test warning')
    adapter.extra['foo'] = 'baz'
    adapter.warning('This is another test warning')
    logger.removeHandler(sh)
    sh.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

When you run it, it prints

```
WARNING This is a test warning [bar]
WARNING This is another test warning [baz]
```

So as you can see, the info in the adapter can be updated after instantiation.